Power BI Clear All Slicer not working in Power Apps Canvas App
I have a PowerApps application and I have Power BI report displaying in my PowerApps Canvas app, all other functionality of my Power BI works except the Clear All Slicers.
the Clear All slicer is not working inside my PowerApps Canvas App

What are you trying to clear exactly? Do you have multiselect slicers, single select slicers,  table selections, etc?
